# When I try to create a user I get this error "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "FK_IMPORTACAO": invalid identifier"

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to create two columns for my user, one taking the ID of "IMPORTACAO_USUARIO" and the other just to save a character.
but whenever i try to create a user i get error ""could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement" by postman or "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "FK_IMPORTACAO" by terminal.

My query:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_IMPORTACAO_USUARIO START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

CREATE TABLE IMPORTACAO_USUARIO (
    ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    DATA_CADASTRO TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    FK_USUARIO NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_IMPORTACAO_USUARIO FOREIGN KEY (FK_USUARIO) REFERENCES USUARIO
);

ALTER TABLE USUARIO ADD FK_IMPORTACAO NUMBER(10,0);

ALTER TABLE USUARIO ADD IMPORTADO VARCHAR2(1);

ALTER TABLE USUARIO
    ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_USUARIO_IMPORTADO" FOREIGN KEY ("FK_IMPORTACAO") REFERENCES IMPORTACAO_USUARIO ("ID");
```

My entity:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "FK_IMPORTACAO", referencedColumnName = "ID",
        foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_USUARIO_IMPORTADO"))
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private ImportacaoUsuario importado;

@Column(name = "IMPORTADO")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Eboolean usuarioImportado;
```

Comment: Are you getting the error on the last `alter table`, or on an `insert` statement? You appear to have foreign keys that point back and forth between both tables. Why, if the relationship is many-to-one? One should be the parent (with the master ID) and the other the child (with the foreign key). If you need a many-to-many relationship, that generally requires a third table, with foreign keys that point to both parents and perhaps a unique constraint on the set of foreign keys to avoid duplicate relationships.

Comment: In this case, i need to save Many users to One Importation and I need save One user to One importation. Like, there will be a user who created the import and there will be users who will be imported, these users who were imported received the id of the import table and the import table will receive the id of the user who created the import.

Comment: This error and the language used seems like you are trying to execute DDL statements as a query - where and when exactly do you get the exception and what does that exception state? The error mentions FK_IMPORTACAO doesn't exist, but not the query used -  Please show the SQL involved.  How are you sure that it exists in the table in question? Is there any reason you added FK_IMPORTACAO as NUMBER(10,0) when the ID it references is Number(10)?